# Optimizing FRP Systems

Tags: haskell, frp

I have to write a paper on optimizations of Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) systems.

Here are the the references I have found so far.

- *Dynamic Optimization for Functional Reactive Programming using Generalized Algebraic Data Types*, Henrik Nilson
- *Lowering: A Static Optimization Technique for
  Transparent Functional Reactivity*, Kimberly Burchet et al.

Besides that, has anyone any other references or suggestions how to optimize the graphs of FRP systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the causal commutative arrows stuff here: http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/publications/publications-chronologically/

There's also a very nice related work section at the end of the pldi Elm paper, which gives a bunch of references one may wish to chase down: http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~chong/pubs/pldi13-elm.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: Don't think of FRP in terms of graphs or other concrete representations. Then imagine other possibilities such as code generation, perhaps using the GHC API or LLVM.